# Terraform: Create multiple Kubernetes manifests using templates

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have a requirement to execute multiple Kubernetes manifests of the same kind. Just names, action, and port changes

my `networkpolicy.yaml.tpl`

```
${yamlencode(
    apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    metadata:
      name: ${name}-policy
    spec:
      action: ${action}
      rules: 
      - to:
        - operation:
            ports: [for port in ports : "${port}"]
)}
```

values that need to be populated for each microservice

```
| --------  | -------- | --------------| --------------|
| name      | frontend | backend       | middleware    |
| action    | allow    | allow         | allow         |
| ports     | 8080,443 | 4731          | 8751,7542     |
```

Example `networkpolicy.yaml` after generation

```
    apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    metadata:
      name: frontend-policy
    spec:
      action: allow
      rules: 
      - to:
        - operation:
            ports: ["8080", "443"]
```

how can I achieve this? I am not clear as how-to write `main.tf`

```
    resource "kubernetes_manifest" "istio-config" {
      manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/networkpolicy.yaml.tpl", {
        name     =
        action   = 
        port     =  
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using kustomization?

Comment: @mecaf I need this in terraform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `loop`

**Example**

```
menifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/networkpolicy.yaml.tpl", {
    name = var.name
  })
```

update the **networkpolicy.yaml.tpl** file

```
%{ for s in nameservers ~}
name ${s}
%{ endfor ~}
```

If you don't want to edit the tpl file you can edit the main.tf directly

```
name = <<-EOT
    %{ for s in var.name ~}
    name ${s}
    %{ endfor ~}
  EOT
```

Ref : https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile

Read more about simple loop : https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9

You can use the **count** or **for_each** loop to simple make it possible.

Comment: How would you handle this for multiple yaml files?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each). You can declare a [local values block](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals) and then loop over that block, replacing what you need. f.e.:

```
locals {
  services = {
    frontend = {
      action = "allow"
      ports = [8080,433]
    }
    backend = {
      ...
    }
    middleware = {
      ...
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "istio-config" {
  for_each = local.services
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("${path.module}/networkpolicy.yaml.tpl", each.value)
}
```

Comment: I have around 100 microservices. So having them all in locals, main.tf may not be a right approach

Comment: In terraform you can divide the files as per your preference. Separate the locals into a locals.tf file is what I do. Even multiple files, per domain if that makes more sense. But somewhere you will have to keep that mapping anyway.